# Is there a C++/C++11 analogue to python iteration over both index and value "for i, v in enumerate(listVar):"?

Tags: python, c++, c++11, iterator

Is there a C++ analogue to the python idiom:

```
for i, v in enumerate(listVar):
```

i.e. I want to iterate with access to both the index and the value of the container I'm iterating over.

Comment: Do you mean s.th. like `for(auto it : enumerate())`

Comment: AFAIK there is no language feature to do this, and there isn't anything in the standard library you can trivially use. You would have to implement something, or use an ugly outer scope counter variable.

Comment: @juanchopanza: What about an iteration variable that returns a tuple?

Comment: @RobertHarvey That would be filed under "implement something". You need a transformation from the container you want to iterate over to some kind of pair iterator.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Sure, I was just kinda hoping to see something like that.  I am disappoint.

Comment: You can implement `enumerate()` yourself so it's as easy as `for (auto &&iv : enumerate(listVar))`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f79bf773f4594ff1

Comment: [std::views::enumerate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/enumerate_view) is a C++23 solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it the following way. Let assume that the container is `std::vector<int> v`

Then you can write something as

```
std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0;

for ( int x : v )
{
   // using x;
   // using v[i];
   ++i;
}
```

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

   std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0;
   for ( int x : v )
   {
      std::cout << x << " is " << v[i] << std::endl;
      ++i;
   }
}
```

However there is a problem that the iterator shall be a random access iterator. Otherwise you may not use the subscript operator.

Comment: Show them with `enumerate()` ...

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I know neither python nor enumerate() :)

Comment: Also if you have `continue`s, you will have to add the `++i` in every `continue`, which is annoying